# Best way to update a single column in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

So im fairly new to coding, and have just started on a project for fun.
I try to build a RPG game, and i have got to the point where players can fight and take damage. So i want to add a passive health regeneration.

So i was thinking that i would use a conjob to request a php file every 10min and update all players HP with +10.

What i have got with my very poor MySQL knowlege is;

```
<?php
/* 
 * hp_reg.php, auto updater +10hp to players.
 */

    //DATABAS CONNECTION
    $dbserver="my";
    $dbusername ="db";
    $dbpassword ="conection";
    $db ="information";

    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db);
    $query = "SELECT health FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $newhp = $result + 10;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(health) VALUES ($newhp)";
```

Wich clearly will not work at all! 
Any tips on what to change in order to get it to work?
All pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: $query = "UPDATE users SET usersname='john'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET health = health + 10";
```

**Updated Code**

```
 <?php
/* 
* hp_reg.php, auto updater +10hp to players.
*/

//DATABAS CONNECTION
$dbserver="my";
$dbusername ="db";
$dbpassword ="conection";
$db ="information";

//CREATE CONNECTION
$conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db);

$sql = "UPDATE users SET health = health + 10";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Thanks alot fot your help! :) Much appreciated!

Comment: *Happy Coding Bro* Cheers. !! @Xirez

Answer (score 1):

To increase the `health` column of all users by 10, you can execute the following query:

`UPDATE users SET health = health + 10`

Comment: Thanks alot fot the quick reply! :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. you want update `health` of **One** user;
2. each user have an unique id;
3. the unique id is stored in your database as `userID` (if not, change it with your correct field name);

you have to try in this way:

```
$query = "SELECT health FROM users WHERE userID='$userID'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query );

$newhp = $row['health'] + 10;
$query = "UPDATE users SET health='$newhp' WHERE userID='$userID'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
```

At last, take a look to [how preventSQL-injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [how check if your result is empty](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)